# give name to odd/even columns of data fame in r with specific pattern

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe :my.df with several columns. I want the odd columns have names like x.1 , x.2, ... and even columns have name as y.1 , y.2 , ... I use the code below. but it does not do what I want. any suggestion how to do this?

```
col_odd <- seq_len(ncol(my.df)) %% 2
colnames(my.df[ , col_odd == 1]) <- paste("x", 1:100, sep = ".")
colnames(my.df[ , col_odd == 0]) <- paste("y", 1:100, sep = ".")
```

thank you for your answer. this the code to get this. in case any beginner like myself would want this:

```
col_odd <- seq_len(ncol(my.df)) %% 2
colnames(my.df)[col_odd == 1]) <- paste("x", 1:100, sep = ".")
colnames(my.df)[col_odd == 0]) <- paste("y", 1:100, sep = ".")
```

Comment: You need `colnames(my.df)[col_odd == 1] <- ..`

Comment: thank you very much